# Sending a newly created emoji after guild.emojis.create()

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an `addemoji` command and I want it to send the new emoji created after the bot creates it. It sends like `:emojiname:` instead of the actual emoji added. How can I define the new emoji added? Somebody suggested that I use `console.log` but I have no idea how to use that information that it puts inside the log.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'addemoji',
  description: 'ping pong',
  execute(message, args) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const PREFIX = 'ly?';
    const load = '<a:loading:824515478939762699>';

    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'addemoji')) {
      if (message.guild.me.permissions.has('USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS')) {
        if (message.guild.me.permissions.has('MANAGE_EMOJIS')) {
          if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_EMOJIS')) {
            const match = /<(a?):(.+):(\d+)>/u.exec(message.content);
            if (!match)
              return message.reply(
                'Please include a custom emoji in your message!',
              );
            // animated will be 'a' if it is animated or '' if it isn't
            const [, animated, name, id] = match;
            const url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${id}.${
              animated ? 'gif' : 'png'
            }`;
            const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
            const nameid = `<:${name}:${id}>`;

            message.guild.emojis.create(url, name);

            let newname = console.log(name);
            let newid = console.log(id);

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(`Emoji added! <:${newname}:${newid}>`)
              .setColor(0x7732a8);
            message.channel.send(embed);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `console.log` is a built-in function used to log i.e variables to the console. It returns `undefined`. If you do `newname = console.log(name)`, newname will be undefined. Try to use name and id instead.

Comment: @Daerendor I tried name and id and it sends the name and id of the emoji I sent in the original message, I'm trying to define the new custom emoji that it adds

Comment: You may wanna try to use .then to check that the emoji is correctly created, and to get back its properties. Here is how you can do it:
`message.guild.emojis.create(url, name).then(createdEmoji => {
    console.log(createdEmoji);
    // here you can create the embed with the properties that you get in the console
}`
if anything goes wrong when creating the emoji, it'll show it

Answer (score 1):

[GuildEmojiManager#create()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmojiManager?scrollTo=create) returns a Promise with the newly created emoji. You can access and display the new emoji by handling this promise, then using the `<:name:id>` wrapper for emoijs

```
message.guild.emojis.create(url, name).then(newEmoji => {
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Emoji added! <:${newEmoji.name}:${newEmoji.id}>`)
      .setColor(0x7732a8)
   message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work, also I don't wanna log it, I just want it to send the new custom emoji. toString() doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I apologize, I've edited my answer with a different approach